# How to use namerefs in Bash?

Tags: bash, reference, declare

How do I use namerefs in Bash? I'm a beginner and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

My code is just this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -n foo="bar"
```

And I immediately get the following error when I run it:

```
declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
```

I couldn't find anything online to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add your bash version to your question (no comment). `declare -n` where added with bash version 4.3.

Comment: If this is MacOS, `/bin/bash` is 3.2, too old to have the feature.

Comment: @Cyrus + CharlesDuffy Thanks! That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I just had to upgrade my Bash to the newest version (for me, 5.0.16) and it now works beautifully. Really weird that the latest macOS ships with a painfully outdated version (for me, 3.2.57).

Comment: I thought new versions switched to zsh

Comment: bash 4.0 switched to GPL3, and Apple refuses to be bound by that license. Thus, they're intentionally sticking with the old one (and encouraging users to switch their interactive shell to zsh, much to my personal chagrin) for legal reasons.